# How to execute the VSSadmin with non administrator account?

Tags: windows, powershell, command, account, user-accounts

Is there any way to execute the following command with not administrator user, I can assign permission to the user but I do not want to make user member of administrator group.

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=C:
```

> vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy
>   Service administrative command-line tool (C) Copyright 2001-2013
>   Microsoft Corp.
>
> Error: You don't have the correct permissions to run this command. 
>   Please run this utility from a command window that has elevated
>   administrator privileges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does powershell remoting support version of the powershell to be used on remote target?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032784/does-powershell-remoting-support-version-of-the-powershell-to-be-used-on-remote)

Comment: My answer on the duplicate details how to create session configurations. One of the options in a session configuration is a RunAs user, so you can make the session run as the privileged user and then grant access to the session to the non-privileged user. You should also restrict the session so it can only run the specific function you write, that way the user can't run other things elevated.

Comment: That may solve this problem, but it's not the only way to do so, so it isn't a duplicate.